# How to render GeoJSON from a nodejs API in react-leaflet?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am new to developing, this is only my third or fourth project. I'm experimenting with react-leaflet in combination with a node/express API that serves a GeoJSON object from a PostGIS db. I can't get the data to render, even though it appears that the react app is successfully grabbing the data from the API.

I've looked through all relevant documentation and watched several YT vids and searched through SE.

Following from grabbing the data all the way to attempted rendering in react:

The PostGIS data is a multi-polygon dataset.

**API code:**

api-server/routes/data.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const pool = require('../db');

//get dataset
router.get('/api/data', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await pool.query("SELECT id, ST_AsGeojson(geom)::json as polygon, name FROM public.data");
        res.json(data.rows);

    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('server error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

api-server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/data'));

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('server started on port 3001');
});
```

**react-leaflet code:**

src/components/map.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import "../styles.css"

export default function Map() {
    const [data, setData] = useState()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/data').then((response) => response.json());
        setData(response);
        console.log(data)
    };

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[33.526, -84.354]} zoom={12}>
            <TileLayer 
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <GeoJSON data={data} />
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

After running the GeoJSON through a linter, as suggested by ghybs, it says `Line 1: "type" member required`, and the beginning of the GeoJSON file is this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "polygon": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [
                        -84.316929695,
                        33.587095739
                    ],
...
```

Comment: What log do you get exactly? Is it valid GeoJSON? (You can check with an online GeoJSON linter tool) Can you share a sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I get the geojson return from the API in the console.log(data). I will copy the object and run it through a linter as you suggested. I felt like its not the data, but something I did wrong in the jsx return or the use of state or something. But I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  ST_AsGeojson(geom)::json as polygon,
  name
FROM public.data
```

...returns rows in the form:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  polygon: {
    type: "MultiPolygon"
    coordinates: [/* ... */],
  },
  name: "foo",
}
```

Since you directly return these rows from your server, you just need to extract the `polygon` data in your frontend, e.g.:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/data').then((response) => response.json());
  // Extract the polygon data of each row.
  setData(response.map((row) => row.polygon);
  console.log(data)
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that since I was using `ST_AsGeojson` that the SQL query was pulling straight GeoJSON. Do you know of any way to make sure the API is serving GeoJSON as opposed to whatever its serving now? Should I just drop the `res.json(data.rows)` in favor of just `res.json(data)`?

Comment: If your server responds with `res.json(data)`, then your front will have to access the rows: `setData(response.rows.map(/* etc. */)`